# snmp4j warning log level

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

My problem is the warning log level of this snmp4j trap sender is received as a minor log level but i need a warning log level message to be received ,something like if i was to use coldstart or warnstart pdu notifications ,can anyone help with this error ?

```
public TrapSenderVersion2(String trapIpDestination, int trapPort,
            String message) {
        try {
            String aMessage = message;
            // Create PDU
            PDU trap = new PDU();
            trap.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);
            // trap.setType(PDU.REPORT);

            String baseString = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.6400.";

            OID oid = new OID(baseString);
            trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime,
                    new TimeTicks(5000))); // put your uptime here
            trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID,
                    SnmpConstants.coldStart));
            trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysDescr,
                    new OctetString("Monitor app")));
            // Add Payload
            Variable messaage = new OctetString(aMessage);
            trap.add(new VariableBinding(oid, messaage));

            // need to specify the system up time
            // trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime,
            // new OctetString(new Date().toString())));
            // trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(
            // Oid)));
            // trap.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress,
            // new IpAddress(ipAddress)));

            // trap.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oid), new OctetString(
            // "Major")));
            // trap.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);

            // Specify receiver
            Address targetaddress = new UdpAddress(trapIpDestination + "/"
                    + trapPort);
            CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
            target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
            target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            target.setAddress(targetaddress);

            // Send
            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
            snmp.send(trap, target, null, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Sending Trap: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TrapSenderVersion2("192.168.1.31", Integer.parseInt("162"),
                "Test Trap Message");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OIDs do *not* start with a dot. You should remove it to avoid errors and to improve your programs performance.

Regarding your question: SNMP do not specify a concept like a "severity class" for traps/notifications. Thus, it needs to be part of the MIB specification of the vendor-specific TRAP-TYPE or NOTIFICATION-TYPE. The idea of not-having a severity in the SNMP standard was that the receiver should be able to decide if an event is severe or not.

So, in your case I would think that you need to specify the "log level" in the trap receiver application and not in the sender code.